# Issues with inserting information into MySQL via local file

Tags: mysql

Please bear with me as this is going to be a long mail. As part of an assignment, I'm building up a TAC (Handset) database using MYSQL 5.6.10. I have created a table called TACTest using following SQL command:

```
CREATE TABLE TACTest (TAC VARCHAR(8), Make VARCHAR(384), Manufacturer VARCHAR(128), Band VARCHAR(384);
```

I'm populating this table via a file called test.txt which is stored on my C: drive. Here is the content of that file (6 different handsets):

```
TAC|Marketing Name|Manufacturer|Band
00100100|G410|Mitsubishi|GSM 1800,GSM 900
00440227|This is a Test IMEI|(AEB) Armando Este Banquito|GSM 1800,GSM 900
01283200|Bunting Camera – WX292|Jaguariuna - Brazil|GSM 1900,GSM850 (GSM800)
01237100|WX295 – EU (850/1900)|Motorola|GSM 1900,GSM850 (GSM800)
35599803|Nüvifone A50|ASUSTek Computer Inc|GSM 1800,GSM 1900,GSM 900,GSM850 (GSM800)
01273300|"T410/T410i, T410s/T410si,T510/W510/T510i, X201/X201s, X201i/X201si, X201 Tablet, X201i Tablet, X100e, Edge 13"",  Edge 14"", Edge 15"" , L512, L412 , Edge 13”, Edge 11”, X120e"|Lenovo Mobile Communication Technology Ltd|GSM 1800,GSM 1900,GSM 900,GSM850 (GSM800)
```

And this is the SQL that I use to populate the table:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\test.txt' INTO TABLE TACTest CHARACTER SET utf8 fields terminated by '|' lines terminated by '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (TAC, Make, Manufacturer, Band);
```

Problem is, the Make and Manufacturer columns have missing data in the database after insertion. Here is the info in the database for Make and Manufacturer column:

```
Make    Manufacturer
G410    Mitsubishi
This is a Test IMEI (AEB)
Bunting Camera  Jaguariuna - Brazil
WX295   Motorola
N   ASUSTek Computer Inc
"T410/T410i, T410s/T410si,T510/W510/T510i, X201/X201s, X201i/X201si, X201 Tablet, X201i Tablet, X100e, Edge 13"",  Edge 14"", Edge 15"" , L512, L412 , Edge 13  Lenovo Mobile Communication Technology Ltd
```

Essentially for Manufacturer column, Row 2 has partial info and for Make column, Row 3-6 have partial info?

What am I doing wrong here? Is there something special needs to be done for inserting special character? Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Since there are non-ASCII characters, I think you need to use `character set UTF8` after your `VARCHAR()`s

Comment: This may help you http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=10195

Answer (score 0):

I just ran the queries you gave, and I am getting proper data. Only difference is in our OS I believe( My machine is running on ubuntu)

```
mysql> show create table TACTest \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: TACTest
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `TACTest` (
  `TAC` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Make` varchar(384) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Manufacturer` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Band` varchar(384) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)



mysql> select * from TACTest \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
         TAC: 00100100
        Make: G410
Manufacturer: Mitsubishi
        Band: GSM 1800,GSM 900
*************************** 2. row ***************************
         TAC: 00440227
        Make: This is a Test IMEI
Manufacturer: (AEB) Armando Este Banquito
        Band: GSM 1800,GSM 900
*************************** 3. row ***************************
         TAC: 01283200
        Make: Bunting Camera � WX292
Manufacturer: Jaguariuna - Brazil
        Band: GSM 1900,GSM850 (GSM800)
*************************** 4. row ***************************
         TAC: 01237100
        Make: WX295 � EU (850/1900)
Manufacturer: Motorola
        Band: GSM 1900,GSM850 (GSM800)
*************************** 5. row ***************************
         TAC: 35599803
        Make: N�vifone A50
Manufacturer: ASUSTek Computer Inc
        Band: GSM 1800,GSM 1900,GSM 900,GSM850 (GSM800)
*************************** 6. row ***************************
         TAC: 01273300
        Make: "T410/T410i, T410s/T410si,T510/W510/T510i, X201/X201s, X201i/X201si, X201 Tablet, X201i Tablet, X100e, Edge 13"",  Edge 14"", Edge 15"" , L512, L412 , Edge 13�, Edge 11�, X120e"
Manufacturer: Lenovo Mobile Communication Technology Ltd
        Band: GSM 1800,GSM 1900,GSM 900,GSM850 (GSM800)
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```